# Detecting a specific color in a circular area and adding horizontal lines inside the circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, geometry

I was working to reproduce an optical illusion that you find [here(image)](https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/wNcRvG84RnMWkTAPM5twrR-970-80.jpg.webp) but I having trouble adding horizontal lines inside of the circles:
My attempt so far:

-Detect the certain colors of the circles

-Detect contours, and extract circle center points, and radius

-Then try to draw horizontal lines (which I failed)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = 255*np.ones((800, 800, 3), np.uint8)
height, width,_ = img.shape

#filling the image with lines
for i in range(0, height, 15):
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+3), (width, i+3), (255, 0, 0), 4)
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+8), (width, i+8), (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+13), (width, i+13), (0, 0, 255), 4)

#adding 5 gray circles
for i in range(0, height, int(height/5)):
        cv2.circle(img, (i+50, i+50), 75, (128, 128, 128), -1) 
#finding rannge of gray circles
lower=np.array([127,127,127])
upper=np.array([129,129,129])
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

#contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    #draw circles around the contours
    coordinates = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
     #coordinates and radius:
    center = (int(coordinates[0][0]), int(coordinates[0][1]))
    radius = int(coordinates[1])
    #I wanted to do a sanity check before the for loop (I added a line the longest line should be 2*radius)
    cv2.line(img, (center[0]-radius, center[1]), (center[0]+radius, center[1]), (0, 0, 0), 4)
    
    for i in range(0, radius, int(radius/5)):
        cv2.line(img, (center[0]-radius+i, center[1]+i), (center[0]+radius-i, center[1]+i), (0, 0, 0), 4)
        cv2.line(img, (center[0]-radius+i, center[1]-i), (center[0]+radius-i, center[1]-i), (0, 0, 0), 4)
        

cv2.imwrite('munker.png',img)
```

And here is the result:
[image]

As you can see the values in the for loop are not proportional to the boundaries of the circle, so the lines are short(except the longest line). What am I missing here?

I tried the Hough transform but I had a similar problem.

For more clarity, I write a code to show what I wanted:

```
 for i in range(0, 360, 15):
        x = int(center[0] + radius * np.cos(np.deg2rad(i)))
        y = int(center[1] + radius * np.sin(np.deg2rad(i)))
        cv2.line(img, (x,y), (x, y), (0, 255, 255), 10)
```

[image: img]

I want to merge the yellow dots with horizontal lines. But my math is finished right here. Sorry, it's long, I was just trying to make things clear. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your lines are red, green and blue. So they can be separated by channel.  So make a mask for the circles for each channel and use the mask to determine which colors are front and which colors are in the back from the masks. That way you are not drawing lines inside the circles, just the full lines across the image.

Comment: What a great solution, you're a hero @fmw42, thank you so much! I will add it as the answer. Could you please check my code in the answers? It's solving my problem currently but I just wanted to make sure I did what you meant. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Code looks OK for what you get, but I did not think that was what you wanted, if you wanted the same as in the example image you used in your link where the green lines were over certain circles and red over others and blue over the others with the full r,g,b stripes behind them.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently working on it, I have just added circles and lines separately for each channel I think I'm close to what I wanted. Thank you again @fmw42 much appreciate for sharing your insights.

Comment: Good work. Keep at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fmw42 pointed out in the comment, splitting the RGB channels and applying a mask is very effective at being able to fill the inside of the circles with horizontal lines.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = 255*np.ones((800, 800, 3), np.uint8)
height, width,_ = img.shape
for i in range(0, height, 15):
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+3), (width, i+3), (255, 0, 0), 4)
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+8), (width, i+8), (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.line(img, (0, i+13), (width, i+13), (0, 0, 255), 4)
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
mask_b = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
mask_g = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
mask_r = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
for i in range(0, height, int(height/5)):
    cv2.circle(mask_b, (i, i), 75, 255, -1)
    cv2.circle(mask_g, (i, i), 75, 255, -1)
    cv2.circle(mask_r, (i, i), 75, 255, -1)

#apply the mask to the channels
b = cv2.bitwise_and(b, b, mask=mask_b)
g = cv2.bitwise_and(g, g, mask=mask_g)
r = cv2.bitwise_and(r, r, mask=mask_r)
#merge the channels
img = cv2.merge((b, g, r))

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```